# bootstrap dropdown menu with slidedown in react js

Tags: reactjs, dropdown

I am using bootstrap with react (using the react-bootstrap package ) and i don't know how to add a slideUp and slideDown animation when the menu is toggled. How can i achieve that?

Thanks

i tried using jQuery with the show.bs.dropdown event but doesn't work

```
import * as React from "react";
import avatar from "../../images/avatars/0.jpg";
import DropdownMenu from "react-bootstrap/DropdownMenu";
import DropdownToggle from "react-bootstrap/DropdownToggle";
import Dropdown from "react-bootstrap/Dropdown";
import DropdownItem from "react-bootstrap/DropdownItem";
import $ from "jquery";

interface ITopNavBarUserMenuProps {}

const TopNavBarUserMenu: React.FunctionComponent<
  ITopNavBarUserMenuProps
> = props => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    $(".dropdown").on("show.bs.dropdown", function(e) {
      $(this)
        .find(".dropdown-menu")
        .first()
        .stop(true, true)
        .slideDown(300);
    });
  });

  return (
    <Dropdown className="nav-item no-gutters"  as="li">
      <DropdownToggle
        as="a"
        id="dropdownUserMenuLink"
        className="nav-link text-nowrap px-3"
        role="button"
      >
        <img
          className="user-avatar rounded-circle mr-2"
          src={avatar}
          alt="User Avatar"
        />
        <span className="d-none d-md-inline-block">Sierra Brooks</span>
      </DropdownToggle>
      <DropdownMenu
        alignRight
        className="dropdown-menu-small dropdown-menu-right"
      >
        <DropdownItem as="a" href="user-profile-lite.html">
          <i className="material-icons">&#xE7FD;</i> Proffile
        </DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem as="a" href="components-blog-posts.html">
          <i className="material-icons">vertical_split</i> Blog Posts
        </DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem as="a" href="add-new-post.html">
          <i className="material-icons">note_add</i> Add New Post
        </DropdownItem>
        <div className="dropdown-divider" />
        <a className="dropdown-item text-danger" href="#">
          <i className="material-icons text-danger">&#xE879;</i> Logout{" "}
        </a>
      </DropdownMenu>
    </Dropdown>
  );
};

export default TopNavBarUserMenu;
```